# How to change the year and month values when creating a new variable in R

Tags: r

Example of data

```
pr=structure(list(MDM_Key = 1:7, year = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2020L, 2022L, 2022L), month = c(3L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 11L), 
    recommended_price = c(110.338476, 813.4039876, 661.4400121, 
    117.4398283, 118.3484346, 10.95458941, 34.70254434), profit = c(19610173.66, 
    30172191.56, 10546493.33, 11550829.54, 6311699.08, 21433932.57, 
    9216609.05), date = c("01.03.2022", "01.03.2022", "01.08.2022", 
    "01.03.2022", "01.06.2020", "01.10.2022", "01.11.2022"), 
    subgroup_id = c("01.01.2002", "01.02.2002", "01.02.2002", 
    "01.01.2002", "05.06.2003", "05.02.2001", "05.01.2001")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I need to change the year and month values, by condition. If `year`=2022, then change it to 2023 and change all `month` values to 01.
If the value of the `year` is less than 2022, then change all its values to 2022, and change all values of the `month` to 12. Result into new variable `month_id`

in this little example desired output would be

```
  MDM_Key year month recommended_price   profit       date subgroup_id
1       1 2022     3         110.33848 19610174 01.03.2022  01.01.2002
2       2 2022     3         813.40399 30172192 01.03.2022  01.02.2002
3       3 2022     8         661.44001 10546493 01.08.2022  01.02.2002
4       4 2022     3         117.43983 11550830 01.03.2022  01.01.2002
5       5 2020     6         118.34843  6311699 01.06.2020  05.06.2003
6       6 2022    10          10.95459 21433933 01.10.2022  05.02.2001
7       7 2022    11          34.70254  9216609 01.11.2022  05.01.2001
  month_id
1   202301
2   202301
3   202301
4   202301
5   202212
6   202301
7   202301
```

What is the easiest way to make such transformations. Thanks for your valuable help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following one-liner should suffice:

```r
within(pr, month_id <- ifelse(year == 2022, "202301", "202212"))
#>   MDM_Key year month recommended_price   profit       date subgroup_id month_id
#> 1       1 2022     3         110.33848 19610174 01.03.2022  01.01.2002   202301
#> 2       2 2022     3         813.40399 30172192 01.03.2022  01.02.2002   202301
#> 3       3 2022     8         661.44001 10546493 01.08.2022  01.02.2002   202301
#> 4       4 2022     3         117.43983 11550830 01.03.2022  01.01.2002   202301
#> 5       5 2020     6         118.34843  6311699 01.06.2020  05.06.2003   202212
#> 6       6 2022    10          10.95459 21433933 01.10.2022  05.02.2001   202301
#> 7       7 2022    11          34.70254  9216609 01.11.2022  05.01.2001   202301
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr::case_when()` inside `dplyr::mutate` works fine as well.

```r
pr %>% mutate(monthid = case_when(year == 2022 ~ "202301",
                                  year < 2022 ~ "202212"))
```